# Geospatial searches with Solr (websolr) in Rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, websolr

I am looking to utilize Solr for both text and geospatial searching in a Rails 3.1 app. I see that [websolr](http://www.websolr.com/) supports geo-spatial indexing & searches but the two gems for it ([sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) & [rsolr](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr)) do not seem to (currently) implement it. Sunspot appears to be in the process of adding the functionality but claims that "[geospatial is] experimental and unreleased. The DSL may change."

Are there other implementations of geospatial searching with sunspot + websolr? I've done a bit of googing and come across some but they seem hackish and I'd rather not use what I've found if there is already a core feature being baked in or a more supported approach.

Comment: If you are running your own box take a look at ElasticSearch instead http://www.elasticsearch.org/. Its easier to set up than solr, is schema free and document orientated, and supports sharding when its time to grow. Its based on Lucene (as is solr) and you can use the tire gem in rails.

Comment: @ADAM this will be a heroku deployed project for now. It also doesn't look like tire supports geospatial searches? Thanks for the info though, we may expand to a dedicated environment later!

Comment: Ok ... thought that might be the case so i posted as comment. ElasticSearch rocks for geospatial and has both points + geofencing and faceting. I have found it much nicer to integrate than solr based solutions.

Comment: @ADAM I think I'm going to go with it on EC2. I found this article very helpful article to get it setup: http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/22/elasticsearch-on-ec2.html and the client should be able to use it for free for a year so that should be helpful to them. Thanks man!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sunspot does support geo-spatial search, with some limitations.

Indexing:

```
searchable do
  text :location
  location :coordinates do
    Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new latitude, longitude
  end
end
```

Search:

```
coord = # whatever...
with(:coordinates).near(coord[0], coord[1], :precision => 3)
```

But it's really not precise... It's using geo hashes if I'm not mistaken. So it's possible that 2 points are close from each other but are not found.
Also, you can't nest `near` in facets.

I would follow the advice of ADAM and go for elastic search. That's what I did. You get a lot more control.

Tire also supports geospatial search, but there is no specific methods in the DSL, because it's not needed. They plan to add them later I think.

Indexing:

```
tire.mapping do
    indexes :location, type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :latitude_longitude, type: 'geo_point'
end

def latitude_longitude
    [latitude, longitude].join(",")
end

def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: ['latitude_longitude'])
end
```

Search:

```
filter :geo_distance, distance: "#{distance}km", latitude_longitude: [user.latitude, user.longitude].join(",")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this by the way. I had some issues getting it setup on EC2 (incompatibility with the latest version and the article, I guess) but afterwards it went pretty smooth. :D

Comment: I'm using Gmaps4rails, because I'm also using it to display my maps, but I also used Geocoder in the past.

Comment: I'm using geocoder myself. I'll have to check out Gmaps4rails, may need that functionality in the future. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity: Sunspot has since released version 1.3.0 with support for Solr 3 spatial search, making it a perfectly viable option on Heroku with Websolr.

Comment: If you do this, be sure to set the index type correctly, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21666490/21115).