# Sunspot geospatial search ERROR:unknown field 'location_ll'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geospatial, sunspot

I've been trying to integrate geospatial search into my rails app for a few days now, but keep getting this error when I run rake sunspot:solr:reindex

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: ERROR:unknown field 'location_ll'

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">Place 1</field><field   name=\"type\">Place</field><field name=\"type\">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name=\"class_name\">Place</field><field name=\"location_ll\">42.348065,-71.083623</field></doc> #etc... keeps going on for all the objects/fields being indexed in the table
```

As far as I can tell I'm doing everything correctly as search and indexing works when I comment out the latlon(:location) line in my model, but don't know if its a bug or if I'm missing something. Below is the setup I'm currently using:

rails 3.2.1
ruby 1.9.2p318

Gems
sunspot (2.0.0.pre.120417) 
sunspot_rails (2.0.0.pre.120417) 
sunspot_solr (2.0.0.pre.120417)

:latitude and :longitude are both in float format

Place model

```
searchable do
text :name
latlon(:location) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(self.latitude, self.longitude) }
end
```

I've tried variations in the Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new, including (lat, lon) and (latitude, longitude)

I took a look at https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/203 and as per the suggestions, stopped my sunspot server, deleted the solr folder, deleted the sunspot.yml, reinstalled, and restarted, but am still getting the error. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure schema.xml in the solr folder matches the latest one from here:

https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_solr/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml

Still not working on my localhost, but it is on production

Comment: Thanks this helped.  Additionally, I had lat > 90.0 which is invalid, lon should be <=180 in decimal degrees.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [websolr](http://websolr.com/) you'll need to make sure you set your *index type* to *Sunspot 2.0 for Ruby on Rails (Solr 3)*. Mine was defaulted to *Sunspot 1.3.x for Ruby on Rails*, and this was causing the `unknown field 'location_ll'` error.

I'm using the Heroku addon, and for that you can set the *index type* by running:

```
$ heroku addons:open websolr
```

Then clicking on your index (probably `default`), and selecting from the drop down and hitting change:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that schema.xml is loaded from your solr directory, not from default's gem's directory.